# What probability operations does "at most one of A or B" translate to?

Tags: probability-theory

We are given events A, B. If "the probability of at least one of A and B happens" translates to Pr($A$ ∪ $B$), and "at most one of A and B happens" is the complement of the former, would the probability be Pr($A$ ∪ $B$)<sup>c</sup>?

Comment: The *event* is $(A \cup B)^c$.  The *probability* is $1 - P(A \cup B)$.  Events are sets, probabilities are numbers.

Comment: I was under the impression that Pr(A∪B)c = 1 - Pr(A∪B)..

Comment: That isn't the usual notation, but perhaps your book uses it.

Comment: Maybe that is it. My professor used this notation in lecture. It might have been informal.

Comment: "at most one of $A$ and $B$ happens" is the same as "at least one of $A^c$ and $B^c$ happens" and so the event is $A^c \cup B^c$ which can also be expressed as $(A\cap B)^c $ via DeMorgan's laws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that at most one of $A$ or $B$ happens can be broken down into 3 disjoint cases: neither $A$ nor $B$ happens, $A$ but not $B$ happens, and $B$ but not $A$ happens. This is: 
$$Pr[(A \cup B)^c  \cup (A \cap B^c) \cup (A^c \cap B)]$$
$$=Pr[(A \cap B^c) \cup (A^c \cap B^c)  \cup (A^c \cap B)]$$
$$=Pr[(A \cup A^c) \cap B^c \cup A^c \cap(B^c \cup B)]$$
$$=Pr[B^c \cup A^c]$$
$$=Pr[(A\cap B)^c]$$

Comment: would Pr(A∩B)c equate to (1-Pr(A)) + (1-Pr(B)) - (1-Pr(A∩B))?

Comment: More simply, the probability that at most one of $A$ and $B$ happens is the probability that _at least one_ of $A^c$ and $B^c$ happens, and so the event is $A^c \cup B^c$ and has probability $P(A^c \cup B^c) = 1 - P(A\cap B)$ since DeMorgan's laws tell us that $(A^c \cup B^c)^c = A\cap B$.